# Checkbox onClick issue with jquery

Tags: jquery, onclick, checkbox

i have an issue with checkboxes and jquery. I set and event click on father(div) that check the checkbox, but if i click on checkbox directly it dosen't check.

You can find the code here: http://jsfiddle.net/vaxxis/65MBb/

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about that: http://jsfiddle.net/65MBb/8/ ? 
All that is necessary - wrap inputs in label. Then do not need JavaScipt.

Comment: older versions of IE wont be able to understand what the label is for if you aren't using the 'for' attribute.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because when you click the checkbox the event `$('.ckb').click()` is also fired.
So it **does** get checked, but gets immediately unchecked again right afterwards because of your function.

So in your click() function you have to make sure that it was the **div** that was clicked and not the **checkbox**.

Answer (score 0):

you can look what element was clicked, if its the input, don't run the script, else run it: http://jsfiddle.net/65MBb/14/